# Display month and day only

Tags: php, mysql

I have a date type column in MySQL (yyyy-mm-dd). I'd like to display the month abbreviation and day number only on a php webpage. I do not want to display the year. I did look through http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php but coding isn't something I do everyday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Eg:**

Database Table: Your_Table

Date Field : reg_date

**Code**

```
<?php   
$qry  =  "SELECT reg_date FROM Your_Table";
$res  =  mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0)
{
while($row  =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $date = $row['reg_date'];
    $day_month = date('d M', strtotime($date));

    echo $date.' = '.$day_month.'<br />';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Works great!

Answer (score 1):

Use `date_format` to do this:

```
mysql> select date_format('2016-01-02', '%b %e');
+------------------------------------+
| date_format('2016-01-02', '%b %e') |
+------------------------------------+
| Jan 2                              |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```